# Hazelcast different (de)serialization for clients and mapstore

Tags: caching, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

I am running hazelcast members and clients with below context:

[image: Hazelcast clients, members with persistence]
As depicted in above diagram:

1. I want the clients to control the (de)serialization, and onboard new clients without hazelcast members being involved in serializtion business.
2. Want to make Hazelcast Map persistent based on naming conventions, e.g. All maps with "*Store" matching pattern, needs to be persisted to cassandra db.
3. Since i chose to persist in binary format, I would like same byte[] stored in hazelcast to be supplied to the mapstore interface.

My problem is - hazelcast seems to apply deserializer before calling the mapstore .store() method and looks for the serializer class with originally stored typeId on the server side. The logical solution is either hazelcast does not apply deserializer for mapstore if my mapstore type is byte[], or have let me define deserializer which would work regardless of typeId. Looks like both does not seem to be possible.

Any idea to tackle the problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kiran,

Some addition to @wildnez s answer:

1. Normally, if you have a Pojo & using MapStore, members also need to know the Pojo. But in your case, since you're OK with byte[], you can store entry as byte[] from the client side, meaning your IMap must be IMap. Then members won't be dealing worth any deserialization. So you'll do the serialization manually & store the byte[] to Hazelcast IMap. As alternate, you can define different serializers/deserializers for members & clients and for those classes, you can always return byte[] on the member. I personally prefer the first solution.
2. Define a wildcard IMap config for `*Store` maps & put a generic MapStore implementation. By implementing `MapLoaderLifecycleSupport`, you can get the map name in your MapStore as well if needed. Please see http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#storing-entries-to-multiple-maps
3. If your Map is IMap then you'll get `byte[]` in your MapStore as well, as described in 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gokhan. However, i dont understand why storing manually byte[] would help, clients may have different POJOs to be cached. how would client code know to which clas to redeserialize into from byte[]. Thats where hazelcast api uses the TypeId for deserializers. The problem is since TypeId is stored as part of metadata or byte[] itself, while calling mapstore.store() hazelcast member presumes that it needs to be deserialized using the same TypeId, which i cannot configured on server. Your second point is valuable to me, I was looking for similar API hook. Thanks for that.

Comment: @kiran, I assume you'll store the same type of POJOs in the same map, so by looking at the map name, you can distinguish the POJO type. But this assumes that POJO type is not important when storing data to Cassandra. You can even but typeId to byte[] you created & on the client side deserialize based on that. If you can share one of the POJOs, then I can give more ideas about how you can use both options I mentioned.

Comment: I have pushed my code here https://github.com/kiranpatel11/cart-demo. There 2 mvn projects  - "cart" for client and "hazelcast-member" for server.

Comment: please check this working example: https://github.com/gokhanoner/generic-serializer. The issue in your code is, typeId also sent to the member so you need a single serializer on the client side, global serializer, and a single one on the member with the same ID. You can wrap the byte[] to a simple POJO and that's it. If you check the project that I shared, you'll see that it's working for different types.

Answer (score 0):

In default case (in-memory-format set to BINARY) Serialisation and Deserialisation happens only on client side. However, you are using MapStore that requires Hazelcast to provide the actual entry object to the **MapStore.store** method, hence the deserialisation on server. Otherwise you would only be receiving a byte[] in MapStore.

Comment: I do understand that, but I am looking for solution to avoid TypeId based deserialization on the server side as I am simply expecting from byte[] to byte[] when mapstore.store() is invoked.